# Ruby URI Manipulation

Tags: ruby, rest, uri

Is there any way to manipulate a URI in Ruby to accept parameters without the use of `?` and `&`?

For example, I wish to do the following:

`http://localhost:5000/service/get/ip/port`

instead of

`http://localhost:5000/service?ip=192.168.1.1&port=1`

To return information for a given device. This would utilizes a fully REST-based interface.

example code:

```
hello_proc = lambda do |req,res|
  res['Content-Type'] = "text/html"
  res.body = %{
     <html><body>
      Hello. You are calling from a #{req['User-Agent']}
      <p>
      I see parameters: #{req.query.keys.join(', ')}
     </body></html>
  }
end
```

Using this URL: http://localhost:5000/a/b
In the above, req's output for a given URL would be:

`GET /a/b HTTP/1.1`

Within 'req', how may one go about handling the URI?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you using Rails, Rack or something else to handle the http request?

Comment: Yes, WEBrick to handle all incoming http requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing is what you're looking for. From the docs for [routing at api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Routing.html)

> Routes can generate pretty URLs. For example:

```
map.connect 'articles/:year/:month/:day',
            :controller => 'articles',
            :action     => 'find_by_date',
            :year       => /\d{4}/,
            :month      => /\d{1,2}/,
            :day        => /\d{1,2}/
```

Changing this up a bit you're all set for ips and ports.

> Using the route above, the URL "localhost:3000/articles/2005/11/06" maps to

```
params = {:year => '2005', :month => '11', :day => '06'}
```

Comment: This seems very nice. I will look into this further. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You should try sinatra, it's a very lightweight REST focused layer on top of rack, with it you could do:

```
get '/service/get/:ip/:port' do |ip, port|
  content_type "text/html"

  "IP: #{ip} PORT: #{port}"
end
```

Comment: That would be great, but unfortunately I am working with a service that has been under development on Rails for quite some time. Thank you nonetheless!